# A projective-cofibrant replacement in $\mathsf{sSet}^{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}$ such that $\operatorname{ev}_0Q(S) \cong \operatorname{ev}_0S$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Consider the category of simplicial presheaves $\mathsf{sSet}^{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}$ endowed with the projective model structure, i.e. weak equivalences and fibrations are point-wise.

> I need a functorial cofibrant replacement
> $Q:\mathsf{sSet}^{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}} \to
>  \mathsf{sSet}^{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}$ with the property that
> $\operatorname{ev}_0Q(S) \cong \operatorname{ev}_0S$ are isomorphic in
> $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}$ for every simplicial presheaf
> $S$.
>
> Actually, I would be satisfied if it worked just for all $S$ constant in the simplicial direction, so just for all $S:n \mapsto P$ for some $P \in
>  \mathsf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}$.

**Question 1**

Does such a cofibrant replacement exist? If it does, a reference too would be awesome.

**Question 2**

Before someone answers I add a related less general question. Does there exist a cofibrant replacement (not necessarily functorial) of the point $* \in \mathsf{sSet}^{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}$ with the property that $\operatorname{ev}_0Q(*) \cong * \in \mathsf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}$ ?

Comment: I doubt this is possible--  any cofibrant replacement of $S$ has to be a retract of a representable functor in degree $0$.    So take $\mathcal C = \mathbb Z/2$ and $S$ to be the (discrete) one point $\mathbb Z/2$ set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Before someone answers I add a related less general question. Does there exist a cofibrant replacement (not necessarily functorial) of the point ∗∈sSetCop with the property that ev0Q(∗)≅∗∈SetCop ?

No.  Cofibrations in the projective model structure on simplicial presheaves on C are retracts of transfinite compositions of cobase changes of generating cofibrations, which are given by tensoring a representable presheaf on C with a generating cofibration ∂Δ^n→Δ^n of simplicial sets.

In particular, if a cofibrant replacement of the terminal simplicial presheaf has a terminal presheaf of sets in degree 0, then the terminal presheaf is a retract of a coproduct of representables.

It is easy to construct examples of C for which there no maps from the terminal presheaf to a coproduct of representables.
Indeed, the latter amounts to saying the taking the limit of such a coproduct (consider as a functor from C^op) produces the empty presheaf.

This argument can be leveraged to give a complete description of projectively cofibrant simplicial presheaves, see [Necessary conditions for cofibrancy in global projective model structure on simplicial presheaves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97690/necessary-conditions-for-cofibrancy-in-global-projective-model-structure-on-simp/).