# Is there a practical criterion to determine whether the limit of a diagram of real chain complexes is also a homotopy limit?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, chain-complexes, limits-and-colimits, simplicial-presheaves

Consider a diagram D: I→Ch<sub>**R**</sub> of *real* connective chain complexes.
In the example I have in mind all chain complexes are concentrated in some fixed degree n.

There is a canonical map lim D → holim D from the limit of D to the homotopy limit of D.
I would like to have a practical criterion for determining when this map is a quasiisomorphism.

Of course, a sufficient condition for this would be the injective fibrancy of D.
However, injective fibrancy seems to be [difficult to check](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9490/) in general.

Thus I'm wondering if the fact that we are in the category of **real** chain complexes, which has rather nice properties (e.g., every epimorphism splits)
might yield a more practical criterion.

**Is there a practical way to check whether the canonical map lim D → holim D for a diagram D: I→Ch<sub>R</sub> of real chain complexes is a quasiisomorphism?**

**Motivation** for this question comes from a desire to compute the homotopy mapping space of simplicial presheaves on the site of smooth manifolds
of the form Hom(F,B<sup>n</sup>**R**).
Here Hom denotes the homotopy mapping space (i.e., the simplicial mapping space with the source cofibrantly replaced and the target fibrantly replaced),
B<sup>n</sup>**R** denotes the Eilenberg—MacLane object corresponding to the representable presheaf **R** of real numbers
(note that **R** here is **not discrete**),
and F is the smooth singular set of some smooth manifold X, i.e., F<sub>n</sub>(U) := {Δ<sup>n</sup> × U → X}.

Although the simplicial presheaf B<sup>n</sup>**R** is fibrant in the local projective model structure,
the simplicial presheaf F is not cofibrant, the primary obstacle being the fact that the corresponding simplicial components F<sub>n</sub>
are infinite-dimensional (they are the mapping spaces Map(Δ<sup>n</sup>,X)), whereas cofibrancy in the projective structure
[requires them to be coproducts of retracts of representables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97690/), in particular they must be finite-dimensional.

One can try to circumvent this problem by observing first that any simplicial presheaf is equivalent to the homotopy colimit of its simplicial components F<sub>n</sub>:
Hom(F,B<sup>n</sup>**R**) = Hom(hocolim<sub>n</sub> F<sub>n</sub>, B<sup>n</sup>**R**) = holim<sub>n</sub> Hom(F<sub>n</sub>, B<sup>n</sup>**R**).
Since **R** is contractible, it is plausible to expect that the higher cohomology of F<sub>n</sub> with coefficients in **R** must vanish,
in particular we hope to have Hom(F<sub>n</sub>, B<sup>n</sup>**R**) = B<sup>n</sup> Hom(F<sub>n</sub>, **R**) = B<sup>n</sup> C<sup>∞</sup>(F<sub>n</sub>).

To calculate Hom(F<sub>n</sub>,B<sup>n</sup>**R**) we can use the above trick one more time and observe that every presheaf of sets is equivalent to the homotopy colimit
of its elements, hence we have Hom(F<sub>n</sub>, B<sup>n</sup>**R**) = Hom(hocolim<sub>U→F<sub>n</sub></sub> U, B<sup>n</sup>**R**) = holim<sub>U→F<sub>n</sub></sub> Hom(U, B<sup>n</sup>**R**) = Γ holim<sub>U→F<sub>n</sub></sub> C<sup>∞</sup>(U)[n],
the latter equality coming from the fact that U is representable and therefore cofibrant.  (The functor Γ is the Dold—Kan functor that sends a chain complex
to the corresponding simplicial set.)
If the latter homotopy limit coincides with the corresponding limit, then we have holim<sub>U→F<sub>n</sub></sub> C<sup>∞</sup>(U)[n] = lim<sub>U→F<sub>n</sub></sub> C<sup>∞</sup>(U)[n] = C<sup>∞</sup>(F<sub>n</sub>)[n], which answers the original question.

Answer (score 5):

Since all your complexes are concentrated in a fixed degree $n$, the cohomology of the homotopy limit is $H^{n+r}(\operatorname{holim}D)=\lim^rD^n$, hence a criterion would be the vanishing of higher derived limits $\lim^rD^n=0$, $r>0$. This holds for all finite direct categories $I$, for instance, but in general it is complicated to know. I guess this doesn't help much.

Comment: Do you know a reference for vanishing of higher homotopy limits for finite categories?

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming that categories were direct, and in that case it's sort of trivial, otherwise it's blatantly false. I've edited my answer.