# Joyal's letter to Grothendieck

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Mostly out of curiosity: Where do I find Joyal's letter to Grothendieck in which he defines a model structure on simplicial sheaves?

The question was already asked in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5179/global-fibrations-of-simplicial-sheaves), but that particular part of the question has not been answered yet.

Comment: I am very glad you reasked this question, but I think that for the record we should point out some previous relevant meta discussion on reasking protocol: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1110/how-to-wake-up-an-old-question/1111#1111

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The letter may be found on Georges Maltsiniotis' [webpage](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~georges.maltsiniotis/ps.html) containing material related to Pursuing Stacks. (A [direct link](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~georges.maltsiniotis/ps/lettreJoyal.pdf) to the pdf.)

Comment: I love the fact that the theorem statements are in English, while the whole rest is in French.